# The required field Name is missing from the input structure

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

When I deploy a SQL Server 2008 R2 SSRS Report from Visual studio, it gave me an error message:

```
Error rsMissingElement: The required field Name is missing from the input structure
```

That is it, nothing else, it doesn't give any clue. But I can preview this report in Visual Studio without problems.

How could I know where this error is from, and which part is wrong in my report?

Answer (score 1):

Answer my own question, just in case somebody encounters the same problem.

This error is not happened from the client site, I mean not the visual studio side. It is caused by some conflicts between the report you want to deploy and some the other one already on the SQL Repoting Server.

After I clean up all the existing ones on server and redeploy, the error is gone.